# JavaScript Inside AJAX Content to Self-Reference More AJAX Content Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I asked a similar question just the other day, and thought I had it resolved, but now I realize I do not. I did learn something valuable from the other question, though, so I'm creating this new one rather than removing someone's answer credit. I'll try to be a little more specific about my problem this time around.

I have an *HTML* page that loads in some dynamic *AJAX* content from a *PHP* file using a custom function to call `jQuery.ajax`, e.g.:

```
$('#navigation a').click(function() {
  var getPage = $(this).attr("class");
  generatePage(getPage);
});

function generatePage(pageNum) {
  $('#ajax-content').load(page.php + ' #someDiv-' + pageNum);
}
```

So, in this instance, you click on any link in `#navigation` on the main page and it will drop the content matching its class name (let's say it's "1" in this case, so `#someDiv-1`) from page.php into the `#ajax-content` container which is also located on the main page. Fine and well. That part works.

The problem arises when I attempt to make a link inside the retrieved *AJAX* content the same way. So if the retrieved `#someDiv-1` content contained a link like:

```
<a href="#" class="4">Page 4</a>
```

How could I make it work so that when clicking on it, it dumps the `page.php` contents of `#someDiv-4` into the main `#ajax-content` container? I realize that the container doesn't even exist inside the *AJAX* content, so is there another way to do this?

Seeking an *AJAX* pro! You don't have to hand me the answer, but a strong shove in the right direction would be much appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Note: The HTML spec says class names cannot start with numbers.

Comment: In fact they do not in the actual work; this was done purely for example. But I also didn't know that, so thanks! =)

Comment: So you've probably been here already then =) ? http://beski.wordpress.com/2010/11/01/jquery-ajax-link-inside-ajax-loaded-content-problem/

Comment: No, I had not been there. But I am thoroughly appreciating the examples now. Thank you kindly, sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make a jQuery event handler that looks for that class name and changes the URL on that element.

I'd probably make it easier by doing it this way:

```
<a href="#" class="linkto _4">Page 4</a>
```

This way you can select all the elements with a "linkto" class, `$(.linkto)`, and parse the other class names to build the URL for the event handler.

jQuery's `.on()` and `.live()` will automatically hook up the event handlers to content that have been loaded via AJAX.

Alternately you can use the HTML5 `data-` attributes to hold the URL information instead of a class name:

```
<a href="#" class="linkto" data-alt_url="_4">Page 4</a>

$('.linkto').data('alt_url')
```

Comment: Holy hell, .on() is above my paygrade. Looks like I've got some learnin' to do! Thanks.